# Trabajar con un objeto serializado extraido de un fichero.ser en Java

Tags: java, serialización, object, stream

Buenas tardes.

Soy principiante en Java y estoy trabajando ahora mismo con el almacenamiento de objetos en archivos serializados mediante los métodos de la clase `Object` (`ObjectInput` y `ObjectOutput`).

A la hora de guardar el objeto no tengo problemas, pero cuando intento agregarlo al programa, no tengo mucha idea de como hacerlo, en lo que a declaración e inicialización de ese mismo objeto extraído del archivo serializado se refiere.

Este es mi código para cargar el objeto

```
    private File player= new File("./data/players.ser");

    public void loadPlayer(){
        try {
            ObjectInput input = new ObjectInputStream(new FileInputStream(player));
            //Procedimiento para realizar el input.readObject(); ???
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Por favor edita tu pregunta. ¿a qué te refieres con `pero cuando intento agregarlo al programa, no tengo mucha idea de como hacerlo`, agregar qué, el objeto?

Comment: No quedaría bien que escribiera objeto dos veces seguidas, ¿no? "A la hora de guardar el **objeto** no tengo problemas, pero cuando intento agregar el **objeto** al programa[...]". Sería una redundancia innecesaria. Saludos!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
private File player= new File("./data/players.ser");

public void loadPlayer(){
    try {
        ObjectInput input = new ObjectInputStream(new FileInputStream(player));
        //Procedimiento para realizar el input.readObject(); ???

        TuClase objetoSerializable = (TuClase)input.readObject();//Realizas el casting hacia el objeto de tu clase
        input.close();

    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

No olvides que los archivos generados con TuClase, no encajarán en el Cast (se le llama Casting a la asignación de objetos compatibles de distinto tipo) si modificas la clase -tendrías que generar otra vez archivos- a menos que defines el serialVersionUID -como señala en la página anexa Chuidiang- siendo muy posible requieras modificar cuando estes desarrollando

[Chiudiang: Serialización de objetos en java](http://chuwiki.chuidiang.org/index.php?title=Serializaci%C3%B3n_de_objetos_en_java)

[Class ObjectInputStream](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/ObjectInputStream.html)

Comment: @JD0001 eso parecería ser una pregunta diferente.. Te recomendaría aceptar esta respuesta (si solucionó tu problema), y formular una nueva pregunta mostrando el código con la declaración de ambas clases

Comment: Hola @JD0001 te invito a realizar una nueva pregunta si tienes otra duda, no hay problema alguno en ello :).

Comment: Si hermano, secundo lo dicho por JD0001

En todo caso, por mi parte, en relación a lo que preguntabas, no agregué más por que no sabía la respuesta XD

Saludos